# Create trigger update SQL table

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

I want to create a trigger update the table `khohang` and table `Dothan`.

Here is my SQL:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_update on dathang
AFTER UPDATE AS
BEGIN
 UPDATE khohang INNER JOIN dathang on khohang.mahang =dathang.mahang
    SET khohang.soluong = khohang.soluong - (SELECT soluong FROM dathang where khohang.mahang = dathang.mahang)
END
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Tagged with `mysql` because of the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trigger occurs when a (BEFORE/AFTER insert, update, delete) action perform on the table, so trigger fired on that action and perform some action on the same or different table. 
This is the formate of Trigger

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `database_name`$$

DROP TRIGGER  `Tigger_name`$$

CREATE 
    TRIGGER `Tigger_name` BEFORE/AFTER INSERT /UPDATE/DELETE ON `Table_1` /* trigger fire from this table*/
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        /* (query) action perform */ 
        update table_2 set field_1="value" where table_2.id=New.field_1; /*New.field_1 is refrance Table_1.field_1. which record effect by action*/
    END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

reference :https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: Thank you, by looking I created trigger for my works as below, 

DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE TRIGGER calculate_score 
BEFORE INSERT 
ON useranswers 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 SET NEW.points = (NEW.dynamiccount + (NEW.staticcount*2));
END$$ 
DELIMITER ;